# Create variable with conditions on other multiple variables

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I'm trying to create variable with conditions on other multiple variables.

For example, I have 5 variables, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`. They ranges from 1 to 8.

I want to create new variable, `grade`, with conditions below.

1) If any of variables (`A` to `E`) are under 2, the grade will be 1

2) if all of variables are more than 3 and any of variables are between 3, 4, the grade will be 2.

3) if all of variables are more than 5, the grade will be 3.

I create dataset `test` arbitrarily.

```
test<-data.frame(A=c(4,7,4,1,4),
                 B=c(8,8,6,5,8),
                 C=c(6,5,6,7,5),
                 D=c(7,8,7,5,8),
                 E=c(5,7,8,5,5))

test
```

In this case, the `grade` will be 2,3,2,1,2.

I tried `mutate_at` function with `vars` and `one_of` function. However, it didn't return what I expected.

```
test<-test%>%mutate_at(
  vars(one_of("A","B","C","D","E")),
  funs(grade=case_when(. %in% c(1,2)~1,
                       min(.) %in% c(3,4)~2,
                       min(.) %in% c(5,6,7,8)~3)))

test

  A B C D E A_grade B_grade C_grade D_grade E_grade
1 4 8 6 7 5      NA       3       3       3       3
2 7 8 5 8 7      NA       3       3       3       3
3 4 6 6 7 8      NA       3       3       3       3
4 1 5 7 5 5       1       3       3       3       3
5 4 8 5 8 5      NA       3       3       3       3
```

I would appreciate for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new version of `dplyr`, installed via `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` and the new `c_across` to get what you want easily. Note that the result doesn't have a 3 because I interpreted your logic as `> 5` rather than `>= 5`.

```r
library(dplyr)

test<-data.frame(A=c(4,7,4,1,4),
                 B=c(8,8,6,5,8),
                 C=c(6,5,6,7,5),
                 D=c(7,8,7,5,8),
                 E=c(5,7,8,5,5))

test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grade = case_when(
    sum(c_across(A:E) < 2) > 0 ~ 1,
    sum(c_across(A:E) > 5) == 5 ~ 3,
    TRUE ~ 2
  ))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A     B     C     D     E grade
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     8     6     7     5     2
#> 2     7     8     5     8     7     2
#> 3     4     6     6     7     8     2
#> 4     1     5     7     5     5     1
#> 5     4     8     5     8     5     2
```